# Exporting Xilinx ISE simulation results into text file

Tags: verilog, simulation, xilinx

(Using ISE Design Suite 14.7)

I have been trying to export the simulation results into a text file or CSV file, but I could not find a way to do so. I want to print output (in 20-bit signed decimal) at every clock edge for some 1000 entries and save it in a file for analog wave plot and other analysis in MATLAB.

Another problem: I also have tried using the `$display` statement to print `%sd`, but the software is having some internal problems and numbers are not printed correctly, rather it is printing weird symbols `”d` , `~d` , `òd` , `Âd` (should have been 1000, 1600, 2000, 2400, etc.). However, waveforms are displaying results correctly.

Example: I want to print `xn[19:0]` in signed decimal format to a CSV file.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no signed formatting; `%sd` means a *string* formatted argument, followed by the character 'd'.

If you want output signed, the argument needs to be signed. If `xn` is declared as `reg signed [19:0] xn`, then just use the `%d` format with the `xn` as the argument. Do not use `xn[19:0]` as the argument because *any* part select of a signed variable becomes unsigned even when you select the whole variable. Otherwise you can use `$signed(x[19:0])` as the argument.